# Unable to fetch Ö , å from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to fetch those Ö , å  from database . What i am missing in my MySql query.

Here is my query.. Thank you.

```
<?php  include('config.php');
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,'select * from work ');
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 ?>

<h5>
    <?php  echo $row['work_desc'];?>
</h5>

<?php
    }
?>
```

My charset is set in UTF-8 ...

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: What does "unable to fetch" mean.

Comment: @Mr.Developer yaaa its coming with this type " fÃ¶r vÃ¥ld " of letters .

Comment: And is the page encoding utf8? Is connection encoding utf8?

Comment: @zerkms i mean to say i am getting error in letters .. i am getting this type of letters " fÃ¶r vÃ¥ld "

Comment: @zerkms yes my charset is in utf-8

Comment: "yes my charset is in utf-8" --- this does not answer questions I asked. But anyway, all the info is available in the duplicate.